# quebrar linha node.js utilizando fs

Tags: node.js

Preciso imprimir a variavel resultado com quebra de linha em um arquivo txt, tenho o seguinte código :

```
var Resultado = formatters.addTrailingZeros(req.query.Nrbanco, 3)        + 
    '0000'                                                              + 
    '0'                                                                 + 
    formatters.addEspacos(' ', 9)                                       + 
    formatters.addTrailingZeros(req.query.TipoInscricao, 1)             + 
    formatters.addTrailingZeros(req.query.IncricaoCedente, 15)          + 
    formatters.addTrailingZeros(req.query.Convenio, 20)                 + 
    formatters.addTrailingZeros(req.query.Agencia , 5)                  + 
    formatters.addTrailingZeros(req.query.AgenciaDigito , 1)            + 
    formatters.addTrailingZeros(req.query.Conta , 12)                   + 
    formatters.addTrailingZeros(req.query.ContaDigito , 1)              + 
    ' '                                                                 + 
    formatters.addTrailingZeros(req.query.Cedente , 30)                 + 
    formatters.addEspacos('CEDRED' , 30)                                + 
    formatters.addEspacos(' ', 10)                                      + 
    '1'                                                                 + 
    formatters.addTrailingZeros(req.query.DataGeracaoArquivo , 8)       + 
    formatters.addTrailingZeros(req.query.HoraGeracaoArquivo , 6)       + 
    formatters.addTrailingZeros(req.query.NumeroRemessa, 6)             + 
    '087'                                                               + 
    formatters.addTrailingZeros(0, 5)                                   + 
    formatters.addEspacos(' ', 20)                                      + 
    formatters.addEspacos(' ', 20)                                      + 
    formatters.addEspacos(' ', 29);                   

// Aqui preciso inserir uma quebra de linha já tentei o \n e não funcionou

Resultado = Resultado +
    formatters.addTrailingZeros(req.query.Nrbanco, 3)                   + 
    '0001'                                                              + 
    '1'                                                                 + 
    'R'                                                                 + 
    '01'                                                                + 
    '  '                                                                + 
    '045'                                                               + 
    ' '                                                                 + 
    formatters.addTrailingZeros(req.query.TipoInscricao, 1)             + 
    formatters.addTrailingZeros(req.query.IncricaoCedente, 15)          + 
    formatters.addTrailingZeros(req.query.Convenio, 20)                 + 
    formatters.addTrailingZeros(req.query.Agencia, 15)                  + 
    formatters.addTrailingZeros(req.query.AgenciaDigito , 1)            + 
    formatters.addTrailingZeros(req.query.Conta , 12)                   + 
    formatters.addTrailingZeros(req.query.ContaDigito , 1)              + 
    ' '                                                                 + 
    formatters.addEspacos(req.query.Cedente , 30)                       + 
    formatters.addEspacos(' ', 40)                                      + 
    formatters.addEspacos(' ', 40)                                      + 
    formatters.addTrailingZeros(req.query.NumeroRemessa, 8)             + 
    formatters.addTrailingZeros(req.query.DataGeracaoArquivo , 8)       + 
    formatters.addTrailingZeros('0' , 8)                                + 
    formatters.addTrailingZeros('0' , 33);
```

var stream = fs.createWriteStream("C:/16/remessa.txt");
   stream.once('open', function(fd) {
        stream.write(Resultado);
        stream.end();
   });

já tentei outras formas de imprimir essa variável em formato txt quebrando linha e não tive sucesso, agradeço se alguém tiver alguma sugestão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você já experimentou concatenar o `\r\n` no fim do que você deseja que seja cada linha?